# How to change a Bezier curve by moving a point on it with the mouse?

Tags: bezier

Like in Illustrator, for example. I. e., grabbing the curve with the mouse and moving the mouse a certain distance.

This is a similar topic:
[Drag a bezier curve to edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316865/drag-a-bezier-curve-to-edit-it/2329537#2329537)

I tried to reproduce **tfinniga**'s answer:

```
P1 = P1 + k1 * V;
P2 = P2 + k2 * V;
```

P0 and P3 must remain in place.

Even adding 1 to K, the result does not meet the expectation.

[image, point shifted 100 up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slff3.png)

Comment: you may also find https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#moulding helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Very detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the answer from **tfinniga**'s post.

From **tfinniga**'s post, we have

```
P = k0*P0 + k1*P1 + k2*P2 + k3*P3 and 
P' = k0*P0' + k1*P1' + k2*P2' + k3*P3'
```

Since you require P0 and P3 unchanged, we have two identities for V

```
V = k1*(P1'-P1) + k2*(P2'-P2)
```

and

```
V = P' - P0
```

So, you can choose

```
  P1' = P1 + c/k1 * V, 
  P2' = P2 + (1-c)/k2 * V
```

where `c` is a constant between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks. How to set **c1** properly? This is the **t**?

Comment: No, 'c1' is not the same as 't' . For 't' value, you have to find it out  itself (which I assume you already knew how to do it as you can compute k1 and k2). For 'c1' value, you can choose any value between 0 and 1.  A typical choice would be using 0.0 if k2 > k1, 1.0 if k1 > k2 or simply use 0.5 regardless k1, k2 values.

Comment: Looks like the **c1** should depend on the location of the click. Maybe from the value of curvature, for example?

On [this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj5ehp3f9xtqcvf/Image000630.png?dl=0) the upper part is the result of two popular programs. Bottom part - **c1** equal to **0.5**.

Comment: **0.07** gives a valid result for this point, but, of course, the result is not correct when dragging any other point.

Comment: Moreover, this result is obtained for `V = P'-P`. For `V = P'-P0` moving point does not match mouse position.

Comment: You may want to use a `c1` value _based_ on `t`, using the cubic ratio value described in https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#abc, so: `c1 = (1-t)³ / (t³ + (1-t)³)`.