# Question about how to general a bezier curve by inputing several points

Tags: c++, bezier

i want to generate a bezier curve pass through several points i input by mouse.These points are more than four,can anyone help me and give me some suggestions about how to implent it?
More thanks.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve the distance between points along the curve first to get your u & v.

Generally, the shortest arc lengths between points approx. the best curve.

p0 and p3 are the endpoints; f and g are two points along the curve.

d1 is distance between p0 and f; d2 between f and g; d3 between g and p3.

Solving for control points, p1 and p2:

Let u=d1/(d1+d2+d3); v=(d1+d2)/(d1+d2+d3)

This is where I link you to:

[How to find control points for a BezierSegment given Start, End, and 2 Intersection Pts in C# - AKA Cubic Bezier 4-point Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315432)

Answer (score 0):

Just write the math into a program. There's nothing we can explain without doing your homework for you.

You can start doing some honest work here: [Wikipedia: Bezier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)

Comment: Thank you very much,i have known how to draw a bezier curve by giving several points to control it,but i do not know how to make a bezier curve go through these given points i input,what' more this is not my homework...