# Find bezier control-points for curve passing through N points

Tags: bezier, points, curve, curve-fitting

Considering the following nice solution for finding cubic Bézier control points for a curve passing through 4 points:

[How to find control points for a BezierSegment given Start, End, and 2 Intersection Pts in C# - AKA Cubic Bezier 4-point Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315432/how-to-find-control-points-for-a-beziersegment-given-start-end-and-2-intersecti/2316440#2316440)

I wonder, if there is a straightforward extension to this for making the Bézier curve pass through N points, for N > 2 and maybe N ≤ 20?

Answer (score 25):

This is a really old question, but I'm leaving this here for people who have the same question in the future.

@divanov has mentioned that there's no Bezier curve passing through N arbitrary points for N >4.

I think the OP was asking how to compute the control points to join multiple bezier curves to produce a  single curve that looks smooth.

This pdf will show you how to compute the control points: [http://www.math.ucla.edu/~baker/149.1.02w/handouts/dd_splines.pdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ebaker/149.1.02w/handouts/dd_splines.pdf)

which I found on this writeup https://developer.squareup.com/blog/smoother-signatures/ from Square about how they render a smooth curve that passes through all the sampled points of a mouse drawn signature.

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.squareup.com/blog/smoother-signatures/

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is no Bezier curve passing through N arbitrary points, where N > 4. One should consider curve fitting to minimize least square error between computed Bezier curve and given N data points. Which is discussed, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729058/how-can-i-get-a-cubic-bezier-curve-closest-to-given-points).

Comment: Yes there is. You can always find a Bezier curve (in fact an infinite number of them) of degree N-1 that interpolates N given points. Your answer is correct for *cubic* (degree 3) Bezier curves.