# Smooth 2d brownian walk with Bezier curve

Tags: python, bezier

I want to generate a Brownina motion smothed by Bézier curve.
I have no problem with the first part:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

def brownian(steps):
    r = norm.rvs(size=(2,) + (steps,))
    out = np.empty((2,steps))
    np.cumsum(r, axis=-1, out=out)
    out += np.expand_dims([0,0], axis=-1)
    return out[0], out[1]

x, y = brownian(30)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

But how can I smooth that path using Bézier curve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you actually want to use a bezier curve, as bezier curves don't go through all of their points (see the [Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B%C3%A9zier_curves) - even in a quadratic curve we don't go through the middle point which is just a "guide"). See more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729058/how-can-i-get-a-cubic-bezier-curve-closest-to-given-points).

You can however use some math to create a bezier curve that smoothly moves through all of your points. To do that, you'll need some [math](https://www.particleincell.com/2012/bezier-splines/) to figure out where to place the "guides", and then you can draw the actual bezier curve using the [bezier drawing code in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/quad_bezier.html).

If you are fine just with any smooth interpolation and not just bezier curves, then [scipy already has some code to do that](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Catmull-Rom spline to create multiple cubic Bezier curves that will interpolate the vertices in your walk path and these Bezier curves will be joined smoothly together. Please refer to this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline) for more details.